# What is a modern alternative to IOBit Uninstaller?

Tags: uninstall

For at least the last 5 years, I've been using IOBit Uninstaller as an alternative to the default Windows installer, in order to make sure that all traces a program installs are removed on uninstall, which I believe IOBit does by keeping a database of files that the most popular programs add.

However, increasingly over the last few years IOBit has made use of questionable and in some cases outright misleading upselling tactics in order to advertise its other products, most commonly in the form of pop-ups that appear during day-to-day use of the OS:

[image]

[image]

While it's simply an annoyance for me, it would be a significant danger for less technically literate users, and for this reason I would never leave the program installed on the computer of anyone that I know.

At the same time, IOBit's interface is much cleaner, more modern-looking and more user-friendly than its closest competitor, Revo Uninstaller, which by contrast hasn't changed much in its interface since it was first released.

Is there an alternative program out there and has a modern-looking interface without the dodgy pop-ups and aggressive marketing? It must also be free like IOBit.

Comment: For something like this I would start with https://alternativeto.net/software/iobit-uninstaller/.